# Django: having trouble redirecting to html page after addingdata in database

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have added a get_absolute_url function in a model called "Album".

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cart:details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

And added a class CreateView to add new albums in the database. 
Everytime I enter an album, the page shows an error in redirection.
CreateView Class:

```
class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['album_title', 'artist', 'genre']
```

The error is :

```
Reverse for 'details' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 4L}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'cart/(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$']"
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: That *is* an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is expecting the keyword `album_id` but you are passing `pk`.

```
return reverse('cart:details', kwargs={'album_id': self.pk})
```